# document is an alias name?

Tags: javascript

Is document an alias of Sys.UI.DomElement in JavaScript? 
I have come across [this example in msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397706%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

```
$addHandler(Sys.UI.DomElement.getElementById("Button1"), "click", toggleCssClassMethod);
```

I used to see only `document.getElementById(id)`. So raised this question.Itmight be sound bad. But I am just kid in JS world.

Comment: What makes you think that `Sys.UI.DomElement.getElementById` is the same function here as `document.getElementById`? `Sys.UI.DomElement` does not exist in a standard browser environment, afaik. Maybe IE is doing it's own thing again...

Comment: @FelixKling it's a part of the ajax library client http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397536.aspx

Comment: @Jared: if i dont use the ajax library references, then the statement --  var departments = $get("Departments"); -- will not be valid right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the two are not the same.  I think your confusion is probably coming from the common misconception that `getElementById` is a function only belonging to `document`.  In fact, you can use `getElementById` on other DOM elements.  Something like this works just fine:

```
document.getElementById("test").getElementById("test2")
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CNc2s/

Notice that the 2nd call of `getElementById` is being called on the DOM element returned by the first call.  This will find an element with an id of `test2` within an element with and `id` of test.

The reason you don't often see things like this is that `id`s must be unique within a document.  So calling it on the document will get the same element as calling it on a containing element.

Comment: How come getElementById can be called again in DOM element returned by the first? That first element class will have this method or its parent class will have the method?

Comment: DOM elements have this function, not just `document`.  So you can call `getElementById` on the DOM element returned by the first call.

Comment: Thanks James, so the document is an object of what?

Answer (score 2):

No, `document` is not an alias for `Sys.UI.DomElement`.  This can be demonstrated with a quick experiment in the IE javascript console.

```
document.name = "hello";
console.log(Sys.UI.DomElement.name);  // Prints undefined
```